# Spring MVC @RequestMapping headers can accept only one value?

Tags: spring-mvc, http-headers, content-type

This will work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = {"content-type=application/json"}) {
    .......
}
```

If I add another value to it like the following, then it will fail and tell me this:

> The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource
>   (Request method 'POST' not supported)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = {"content-type=application/json","content-type=application/xml"}) {
    .......
}
```

I guess this is because Spring thinks the two *content type* values have "AND" relationship but instead I want them to be "OR".

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried doing `content-type=application/json,application/xml`?

Not sure if it would work but putting two `content-type` headers in there I think only one will win.

**OR**

possibily use two `RequestMapping` annotations on the same method with different `content-type` headers?

Comment: "content-type=application/json,application/xml" worked! Thanks!

Comment: @dave G only one `@RequestMapping` is accepted by method

Answer (score 36):

If you are using **Spring 3.1.x**. You can look at using **consumes**, **produces** attributes of @RequestMapping annotation. Here is the Spring blog post on the improvements:

http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements/

Snippet from the doc above:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pets", headers="Content-Type=application/json")
public void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    // ...
}
```

is replaced by:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pets", consumes="application/json")
public void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    // ...
}
```

In addition, if you need **multiple media types.** You can do the following:

```
produces={"application/json", "application/xml"}

consumes={"application/json", "application/xml"}
```

Comment: I have a doubt here - when I write `produces = "application/xml"`, still it gives me the error 406. 

But if write `produces = "application/xml", headers = { "Content-Type=application/xml" }`, then everything works fine. 

So my question is why `produces` is not enough to return XML response and need `headers` to complete the task.