# Sending HTML data through AJAX using Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have an AJAX call which is processed and a jsp page is returned by Spring.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData.do")
public String getData() {
    // ...
    return "data";
}
```

and I am returning `data.jsp`.

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : "getData.do",

    error : function() {
        alert('failure');
    },
    success : function(result) {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

I have servlet mapping in `web.xml` for `.do` files

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

OK, so when I have this `<bean>` definition in my dispatcher, it works fine.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**But, when I change it to this, it fails!**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I need this for JSON. Any ideas?

**Update** : Added stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Foo] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'getData' in servlet with name 'spring'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'getData' in servlet with name 'spring'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @MoritzPetersen Sorry, updated...

Answer (score 1):

It got fixed when I modified the `Accept` header in AJAX as mentioned in this post [Pass accepts header parameter to jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347211/pass-accepts-header-parameter-to-jquery-ajax).

Updated AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : "getData.do",
    headers: {          
        Accept : "text/html; charset=utf-8",         
    },    
    error : function() {
        alert('failure');
    },
    success : function(result) {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought you want to get JSON? Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962023/spring-mvc-requestmapping-headers-can-only-accept-one-value)

Comment: @MoritzPetersen I meant, I need the second setting in dispatcher for JSON.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen The link you provided won't work as that will only add one more level of filtering.