# How to Validate HttpServletRequest using @Valid annotation?

Tags: java, validation, spring-annotations, spring-rest

I am currently working on a rest api and I need to validate the HttpServletRequest object which my Controller method receives. Is there a way to validate it using the @Valid annotation? I need to check the content type, request body? I know we can use the @Valid annotation to validate user defined classes. Can we use the same for HttpServletRequest Class? If not what other options do i have?

thanks,
kayzid

Comment: Can't you do RequestMapping for content-type? `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = {"content-type=application/json"})`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962023/spring-mvc-requestmapping-headers-can-only-accept-one-value

Comment: My method is accepting any content-type but  I just need to make sure that it is not null or has a garbage value. So specifying the content-type in request mapping would be difficult.

Comment: try using consumes in `@RequestMapping`

Comment: how would it work if I want to accept any content-type as long as it is not null or some garbage value with the Consumes in @RequestMapping

Comment: If I create a validator for the HttpServletRequest object say HttpServletRequestValidator can i add it as a validator to WebBinder object using binder.setValidator method call?