# Spring Restful support json data multi language

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have implemented spring restful service. It's working fine as expected, but the problem here is sometimes request body json data have multiple languages like Chinese, French, Japaneses.

**Request Body**

```
{
    "firstName": "demo",
    "lastName": "françois1",
    "email": "你好"
}
```

in Controller method i am getting json data in below format

```
{
    "firstName": "demo",
    "lastName": "ad�la�de",
    "email": "??"
}
```

There is a lot of difference what user gave to rest service and what spring controller method is returning to me. can anyone help me what went wrong?

Comment: Can you share some piece of code of controller? Is it what you are getting in response in browser as well?

Comment: @Braj response am getting in controller method i need to persist json data in database but what user pass and what my controller getting is completely different

Comment: how does client send json data to controller? Is it issue with submitting/sending the data with incorrect encoding from client instead of controller encoding? Add [consume](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--) attribute of `RequestMapping` to test for correct accepted encoding. Follow this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962023/spring-mvc-requestmapping-headers-can-only-accept-one-value)

Answer (score 2):

In `web.xml`, try add a filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/springmvc_path/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Replace the `/springmvc_path/*` part with your springMVC servlet's `<url-pattern>`

Then restart the web server.

Comment: Encoding filter configured correctly but problem is not with filter. something is missing

Comment: @Venu Did u see the messy json value in an IDE (e.g Eclipse), if so, what is the encoding of your workspace? Make sure it's also utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your character encoding is set to utf-8.

If using tomcat something like below in your server.xml will ensure actual uri are correctly encoded with utf-8 chars:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
 enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
 connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
 compression="on" 
 compressionMinSize="128" 
 noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

and web xml

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
 </filter>
```

Comment: @Venu make sure you mapped it correctly, and its getting hit - set some debug points ?