# Using two RequestBody in Spring Restful Service

Tags: rest, spring-rest

I am trying to use two request bodies for a Mapping in Spring Rest.

I have already read through some questions and there are suggestion to use two different methods with consumes one as application/json and other as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I wanted to know if this the only approach or are there any alternatives so that i could use both application/json and urlencoded as my RequestBody.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you need two - `@RequestBody` - one for `application/json` & other for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while conceptually a HTTP request has only one body so two bodies don't make sense to me.

What you are looking for is same method handling two different content - types not two bodies. Body generation / conversion process will vary as per content type but there remains only one body since client will send same data.

Two different content types are already supported as highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962023/spring-mvc-requestmapping-headers-can-only-accept-one-value)

With `consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE}` , you can send both content - types with a single `@RequestBody` by changing content type header in your request.

There can be only one method for a unique `@RequestMapping` otherwise it will become ambiguous mapping.

Multiple mappings can map to single method but vice versa is not allowed.